# Sending Orientation of a LinearLayout as a parameter to a method - java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a method that will add a new LinearLayout to an existing LinearLayout. I would like to send a parameter to this method telling it whether the new LinearLayout should be VERTICAL or HORIZONTAL. This is what I have so far but 'LinearLayout.Orientation' is not the correct name for this parameter type.

```
private LinearLayout addLinearLayout(View linearLayout, LinearLayout.Orientation orientation)
{
    //Create new horizontal linear layout and add to the specified linear layout
    LinearLayout newLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(20, 10, 0, 10);
    newLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.orientation);
    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(newLinearLayout, layoutParams);
    return newLinearLayout;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, what is the type of the parameter I am trying to pass?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use int for the orientation value, LinearLayout.Orientation is the name of the enum but the type is int. Also, why do you cast a LinearLayout to a LinearLayout, its absolutely pointless

Comment: The cast was in some code I found yesterday. I've removed it and you are right that it works fine without. If I use 'int orientation', I get an error underlining LinearLayout.orientation saying it must be HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.

Comment: that LinearLayout.orientation doesnt make sense, you should put just orientation, below answer is correct.

Comment: Actually I did need the cast - I need to pass a View to the method rather than a LinearLayout.

Comment: Then you can cast to LinearLayout or ViewGroup, maybe its better if you make the method param a ViewGroup instead of View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation(int)):

> **public void setOrientation (int orientation)**
>
> (...)
>
> orientation   Pass HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL. Default value is HORIZONTAL.

```
private LinearLayout addLinearLayout(LinearLayout linearLayout, int orientation) {
    //Create new horizontal linear layout and add to the specified linear layout
    LinearLayout newLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(20, 10, 0, 10);
    newLinearLayout.setOrientation(orientation);
    linearLayout.addView(newLinearLayout, layoutParams);
    return newLinearLayout;
}
```

Call this method like this:

```
addLinearLayout(yourLinearlayout, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

The orientation of a Layout seems to be represented by an Integer...

```
private LinearLayout addLinearLayout(LinearLayout linearLayout, int orientation)
{
    //Create new horizontal linear layout and add to the specified linear layout
    LinearLayout newLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(20, 10, 0, 10);
    newLinearLayout.setOrientation(orientation);
    linearLayout.addView(newLinearLayout, layoutParams);
}

// Then you can call your function like this
addLinearLayout(layout, LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```